# Android SurfaceView or Emulator bug

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, surfaceview

I am currently trying to develop a game for android. To accomplish this I am using Android Studio and using the SurfaceView control for drawing my images. The problem is that the surface view only switches between two frames. I am developing for API level 15 and using an emulator.

Example: The X-Position of my sprite is increased with 50px by frame

Frame 1: Drawing sprite at (100,100), X-Position=100

Frame 2: Drawing sprite at (150,100), X-Position=150

Frame 3: Drawing sprite at (200,100), X-Position=200

Frame 4: Drawing sprite at (150,100), X-Position=250

Frame 5: Drawing sprite at (200,100), X-Position=300

and then it continues in the same way for the rest of the time(Frame 2, Frame 3, Frame 2... etc), while the x-coordinate is increased correctly.

The weird thing is that the first few frames the game functions correctly, but then this loop starts. I do know that the X-Position value is incremented correctly(looked this up from the debugger).

I got the problem fixed by restarting the emulator, but I'd like to know if this problem can happen again for a real user of the app. BTW I am coming from Visual Studio and Windows Phone and thus I am not too experienced in android.

My GameThread Class:
Note: The SpriteBatch extends SurfaceView and implements SurfaceHolder.Callback

```
public class GameThread extends Thread
{
private boolean running = false;
private SpriteBatch canvas = null;
private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = null;

public GameThread(SpriteBatch sp)
{
    super();
    this.canvas = sp;
    this.surfaceHolder = sp.getHolder();
}

public void startThread()
{
    running = true;
    super.start();
}

public void stopThread()
{
    running = false;
}

public void run()
{
    Canvas c = null;
    while (running)
    {
        c = null;
        try
        {
            c = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            synchronized (surfaceHolder)
            {
                if (c != null)
                {
                    canvas.onDraw(c);
                }
            }

            sleep(16);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ie)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            if (c != null)
            {
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

SpriteBatch.onDraw:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    StartTime=System.nanoTime();
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

    //Created under initialization
    //Paint PaintCommand=new Paint();
    //PaintCommand.setAlpha(100);
    //MyMatrix=new Matrix();
    //MyMatrix.postScale(0.5f,0.5f);
    //MyMatrix.postTranslate(50,50);

    canvas.drawBitmap(MyTexture, MyMatrix, PaintCommand);

    EndTime=System.nanoTime();

    Game1.Elapsed=(float)((EndTime-StartTime)/1000000000f);
}
```

Comment: It's not a SurfaceView or emulator bug.  Paste the method that does the drawing in your question so we can see what you're doing.  Bear in mind that SurfaceView is double-buffered, and that the screen is not erased for you each frame.

Comment: `canvas.onDraw(c)` doesn't make sense.  Assuming you meant to use some other variable, overriding `onDraw()` doesn't make sense for a SurfaceView -- you'd do that for a plain custom View, not a SurfaceView's surface.  `sleep(16)` is not a great approach; see https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#loops .  Can you show your draw method (i.e. the part that fiddles with the coordinates, erases the screen, draws the sprite(s), etc.)?  I'm assuming from your description that it's fairly simple at this stage.

Comment: @fadden I added the code for spriteBatch.onDraw(). The code does not include all draw calls but they are exactly identical, albeit with other sprites, positions and scales

Comment: My guess is that somehow onDraw() isn't actually doing work and you're just flipping back and forth between the first two frames every time you lock/unlock the surface, but I can't tell from the posted code where things might be going wrong.

Comment: I somehow managed to fix this problem, but I do not know how :)